# Why is depmod necessary for building and working with kernel modules?

Tags: linux, kernel

From what I read, the purpose of depmod is to track dependencies for each kernel module for when it gets loaded. Why can't this be simply determined automatically when the kernel module is loaded, similar to dynamically loading a userspace shared library?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

depmod does more than just compute direct dependencies - it also builds a mapping between hardware identifiers and the modules that handle them. This is used to find the correct module to load for a detected piece of hardware.

As for why it doesn't do demand loading like userspace does, part of this is because the kernel linker is not allowed to access the filesystem, by design. The philosophy in the kernel is the layout of the filesystem is completely up to userspace, and so there's no guarantee that `foo.ko` will be found in `/lib/modules/3.0.1/drivers/somesubsys/foo.ko`. As such, the kernel relies on userspace utilities (like depmod and modprobe) to pass it the raw data for its modules, in the order it needs to load them; if userspace fails in this job, it simply returns an error, and lets userspace deal with the mess.

Comment: but then, modprobe could take care of resolving dependencies from in-module information and probe the corresponding dependent modules first, couldn't it ?

Comment: depmod builds a cache of this dependency information for modprobe's use. actually scanning all modules for this info can take quite a while, so you don't want to do it every time you call modprobe

Answer (score 0):

**depmod utility:**

depmod is a tool that you run during the kernel build process to generate module dependency files. It does that by reading each module in
/lib/modules/<kernel_release>/ to determine what symbols it should export and what symbols it needs. The result of that process is written to the
file modules.dep and its binary version modules.dep.bin. It is a kind of module indexing.

The depmod utility doesn't only build modules.dep and modules.dep.bin files. It does more than that. When a kernel developer actually writes a driver, they know exactly what hardware the driver will support. They are then responsible for feeding the driver with the product and vendor IDs of all devices supported by the driver. depmod also processes module files in order to extract and gather that information, and generates a
modules.alias file, located in /lib/modules/<kernel_release>/modules.alias,
which will map devices to their drivers.